# Who first proved that the euclidean vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be totally ordered with an Archimedean order ($n>1$)?

Tags: logic, terminology, order-theory

The title says it all, but to ad a bit more:

- this is mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space#Examples
- is it in Bourbaki ?
- does it predate the definition of total ordering (maybe by exhibiting some kind of counterexample) ? For instance, did Russell, who had deep philosophical thoughts on the topic of order, know about it ?

Many thanks!
[**edit**: the first version of the question mentioned only "$\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be totally ordered ($n>1$)", which is incorrect and explains the comments and answer. I'd be very interested by the answer to the reformulated question.]

Comment: $\Bbb R^n$ **can** be totally ordered, and rather easily, too (e.g., by the lexicographic order); you must be omitting some additional requirement of the ordering.

Comment: By the [well-ordering theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem), it can even be well-ordered.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking specifically of the product order where $(x,y)\leq (x',y')$ iff $x\leq x'\wedge y\leq y'$? But if that's the case, I doubt the proof would be attributed to anybody as it's quite trivial.

Comment: I may not use the correct terminology, but I read on Wikipedia that the order then cannot be Archimedean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space#Examples  yet $\mathbb{R}$ has the Archimedean property.

Answer (score 1):

The "result" for which you're looking for a citation is wrong: $\mathbb{R}^n$ *can* be linearly ordered for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

To elaborate on Brian Scott's comment: even without the axiom of choice *(which per k.stm's comment implies that every set whatsoever can be ordered, and indeed well-ordered)*, any finite Cartesian power of an orderable set is again orderable. There are various ways to do this, with the most common probably being the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). So since $\mathbb{R}$ is orderable each $\mathbb{R}^n$ is also orderable.

Interestingly, that "finite" bit is important: it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ (= the standard axioms of set theory without choice) that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is not orderable.

Perhaps you're thinking of orderings which "play well" in some sense with the topological or algebraic structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$? For example, the usual ordering $<$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is open when viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, but for $n>1$ there is no ordering on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is open as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$ (with all topologies in this sentence being the usual ones). I don't know when this result was proved; I suspect it's folklore.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It's the last part that I'm trying to refer to. I think the statement I saw mentioned $\mathb{R}^n$ being a vector space with the Archimedean property.